# Put a video on fast-forward, put it back to normal (speed)

Tags: word-usage

If someone fast-forwards a video, is it natural  to use:

> He **put his video on** fast-forward.

And if I want it to play normally,can  I say(telling the other person  who fast-forwarded it)

> Hey! **Put it back** to normal?

Can the same be used for "slow-motion"?

> **Put the video on slow** motion.
>
> **Put it back** to normal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all adjective phrases, with a missing noun "mode" at the end. Fast-forward mode, normal mode, slow-motion mode.

People watch things at normal speed or at slow-motion speed, but nobody watches things at fast-forward speed. So we usually make that a verb ("fast foward it to the good part") rather than calling it a mode ("put it on fast forward until it gets to the good part").